# Difficulty installed Pod in Podfile

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to install the OpenTok pod to my pod file. I have a very big project with many pods installed from the previous developers.

The pod file looks something like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

def common_pods
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.11.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.11.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'BMEApi', :path => 'BMEApi'
pod 'NMRangeSlider'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'ASMediaFocusManager'
pod 'QBImagePickerController', '~> 3.4'
pod 'HPGrowingTextView', '~> 1.1'
pod 'HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Stripe', '~> 8.0'
end

target 'My_Target' do
common_pods
end


target 'My_Target_Appstore' do
common_pods
end
```

When I try to add

```
pod 'OpenTok'
```

to the "common_pods" section, I get a crash in the terminal when I try to run pod install. It says something along the lines of "Oh no, an error has occurred" asking me to write a ticket.

When I open up my project, all the pods files are messed up and Xcode can't locate any of them.

**To test to see if there was something wrong with the framework, I tried installing it on a random test project and it worked perfectly**

So the issue here is why won't it install properly on this project, but it will on the other project, and why does it mess up the entire pod file?

Comment: How about `pod update` ?

Comment: It tries to install then gives the same error, this issue has been persisting for hours...

Comment: If you remove the `pod OpenTok` line now and try again with `pod install --no-repo-update`, are you getting the same issue?

Comment: Yes I get the same error

Comment: recommend you to purge all the files/folders related to Pod (Pod dir, **..xcworkspace, Podfile, Podfile.lock), and use `pod init` to reinitialise again. Be sure to backup the whole project first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add use_frameworks!

So, result pod file (name of the my test project - *stackoverflow-39682480*):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

def common_pods
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.11.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.11.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'

# I Do not have BMEApi lib, so i disable it of me
#pod 'BMEApi', :path => 'BMEApi'

pod 'NMRangeSlider'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'ASMediaFocusManager'
pod 'QBImagePickerController', '~> 3.4'
pod 'HPGrowingTextView', '~> 1.1'
pod 'HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Stripe', '~> 8.0'
pod 'OpenTok'
end

target 'stackoverflow-39682480' do
common_pods
end
```

### Result

[image]